# Removing foreign key in migration fires twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0

I'm trying to make a migration for an ASP.NET Core 6 + Entity Framework Core project.

In the migration, the foreign key of the table must be removed.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Clients_Company",
    table: "Clients");
}
```

When calling in the `Database.Migrate()` context constructor, I get an error:

> 'FK_Clients_Company' is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint

At the same time, the key itself is available (including is located by a request in `sysobjects`) and is deleted, it turns out that
`DropForeignKey` works 2nd time after deletion and does not find the key.

No other manipulations are performed with this key anywhere else.